# Python web crawler using urllib

Tags: beautifulsoup, web-crawler, python-requests, urllib, python-2.5

I am trying to extract the data from a webpage/website. Here's my code:

```
from urllib import urlopen
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import re

webpage=urlopen('http://www.xxxxxxxxx.com').read()
patFinderTitle=re.compile('<title>(.*)</title>')

patFinderLink=re.compile('<link rel.*href="(.*)"/>')

findPatTitle=re.findall(patFinderTitle,webpage)
findPatLink=re.findall(patFinderLink,webpage)


listIterator=[]
listIterator[:]=range(2,16)

for i in listIterator:

    print findPatTitle[i]
    print findPatLink[i]
    print "\n"

    articlepage=urlopen(findPatLink[i]).read()

    divbegin=articlepage.find('<div class="">')
    article=articlepage[divbegin:(divbegin+1000)]

    soup=BeautifulSoup(article)

    paralist=soup.findAll('<p>')
    for i in paralist:
         print i
```

I want to list the title and all the links in the webpage. When I run the script it throws an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "justdialcrawl.py", line 21, in <module>
print findPatTitle[i]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I tried searching Google but I could not find answers.

Comment: Why are you using a very old version of `BeautifulSoup`? Run `pip install beautifulsoup4`, then in your programs use `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot one minor thing:

```
webpage=urlopen('http://www.xxxxxxxxx.com').read()
#                                  this -> ^^^^^^^
```

Your code just generated an `urlopen` object and assigned it to `webpage`. To assign the *contents* of the page, you need `.read()`.

Comment: yeah i changed that , thanks :) but now again error pops out , saying list index out of range , please find the error on the updated question

Comment: @SJith you're using `i` in your inner `for` loop as well as the outer one. Change one of them to something else.

Comment: I tried to change the inner **for** loop variable to __  j __ but still i can't see any changes :(

Comment: @SJith could you provide the actual site you're searching so I can test your code? In the meantime, though, the reason you're getting an error with `findPatTitle` is because your iterator `i` is starting at `2`, but generally there is only one `<title>...</title>` field in an HTML page, meaning `findPatTitle` only has one item in it, at index `0`.

Comment: @SJith also, the whole business with `listIterator` is completely unnecessary. Just use `for i in range(2, 16):` and you'll be fine.

Comment: i tried in your way for crawling the data, now it throws me
`IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond`
When i googled about it, i came to know it was due to my proxy network . The url i used was : **www.netinstructions.com/2011/09/how-to-make-a-web-crawler-in-under-50-lines-of-python-code/**
and the division i wanted was **<div class="disqus_thread">**

Comment: @SJith try visiting that page in a web browser - it's a 404, meaning it doesn't exist. The actual URL is http://www.netinstructions.com/how-to-make-a-web-crawler-in-under-50-lines-of-python-code/

Comment: yeah i checked the link , **http://www.netinstructions.com/how-to-make-a-web-crawler-in-under-50-lines-of-python-code/** is a valid link , i can't see any 404 status code on it